# How to remove Tikz pgfplot ticks from the top, bottom and right borders?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, ticks

I am creating a histogram, which I've managed to do with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=50,
    minor y tick num = 2,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    area style,
    xticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}x,
    yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
    xlabel={EV/EBIT},
    ylabel={Frequency}],
    ]
\addplot+ [ybar interval,mark=no, fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135},draw=gray!5] plot coordinates { (0, 0) (5, 7.6) (10, 40.1) (15, 30.5) (20, 10.7) (25, 4.1) (30, 2.4) (35, 1.4) (40, 1.0) (45, 0.7) (50, 0.4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives:

[image]

But what annoys my eyes, are the ticks on the bottom x-axis, top border and right border. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the yticks only on the left, add `ytick pos=left,`, see section **4.15.2 Tick Alignment: Positions and Shifts** of the pgfplots manual for more details. To remove the xticks altogether, just add `xtick style={draw=none}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick style={draw=none},ytick pos=left, 
    ymin=0, ymax=8000,
    minor y tick num = 2,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    area style,
    ]
\addplot+ [ybar interval,mark=no, fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135},draw=gray!5] plot coordinates { (0, 32) (5, 1228) (10, 6658) (15, 5060) (20, 1786) (25, 684) (30, 404) (35, 228) (40, 165) (45, 119) (50, 72)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! The ticks were properly removed for the top and right, but not for the bottom. I looked in the manual and tried to implement: xtick pos=bottom, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Philip Yes, sorry, didn't read the question carefully enough. Fixed it (I hope).

Comment: Thank you Marmot, that solved my issue! :)